# Check if JSONObject key exists

Tags: android, json, jsonexception

I'm making api calls to a back-end who always has a `JSONArray series` and sometimes has a `JSONArray places`. In the code below, I am trying to write an if statement that says, whenever there is no `places` array, make another http request. However, I am not getting a nullpointer, it just throws a JSON Exception saying there is no value for places. What can I put as the terminating condition, for when `places` has no value? I have tried `places == null` and that hasn't worked.

```
try{
    JSONArray places = passingObject.getJSONArray("places");
    JSONArray series = passingObject.getJSONArray("series");

    if(some condition){
       //do something else
    }
}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.d("JSON EXCEPTION" e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use
http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray(java.lang.String)

```
JSONArray places = passingObject.optJSONArray("places");
if(places == null){...}
```

`optJSONArray();` It returns null if there is no such key, or if its value is not a JSONArray.

Answer (score 4):

Check if the object has a key called places.

```
if (passingObject.has("places") {
    JSONArray places = passingObject.getJSONArray("places");
} else {
    askServerAgain();
}
```

Comment: it will not work if space included in the key like 'some places' is the key.