# Kotlin: Check if JSONObject key exists

Tags: android, kotlin

**I want to check if an entry in my `JSONObject` exists and is the type it should be to avoid an exception when used.**

I found my question almost has an answer for Java [Check if JSONObject key exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32470315/391691) to use the `has()` operator

```
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

var j:JSONObject

        ...

val x:Int = if (j.has("mykey"){
   j["mykey"] as Int
}else {
   0
}
```

If `val x:Int = j["mykey"] as Int` is executed without the check it will throw an exception.

Is there a more *kotlin*ish way, maybe with some Elvis operator or something, of doing this check?

What is good way to get get the type of `j["mykey"]` without risking triggering an exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [optInt (String name, int fallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#optInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) to achieve your task.

> ```
> public int optInt (String name, int fallback)
> ```
>
> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is an int or can be
> coerced to an int, or fallback otherwise

Your code will be

```
val x: Int = j.optInt("mykey", 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `is` just like `instanceof` in java -

```
if (j.has("mykey"){
    val myValue = j["mykey"]
    if(myValue is Int){
        //Use myValue here
    }
}
```